# неправильная работа операторов сравнения

Tags: python

только учусь программировать, решил сделать программу в которой пользователь вводит число и  она бронирует номер в указанные дни
но с понедельника по четверг номер стоит дешевле, ошибка происходит при сравнении, `if(day != mon | tue | wed | thu | fri | sat | sun |0):` в этой строке, работает только с числом 31, остальные сравнивает неправильно
вот код:

```
def ch():
    mon=31
    tue=1
    wed=2
    thu=3
    fri=4
    sat=5
    sun=6
    sum1=2100
    sum2=2850
    result=0
    day=1
    print("input the day. enter 0 if you want to stop\n")
    while(day != 0):
        day = int(input())
        if(day != mon | tue | wed | thu | fri | sat | sun |0):
            print("wrong day")
        else:
            if(day == mon|tue|wed|thu):
                result = result + sum1
                print(result)
            else:
                if(day !=0):
                    print("it will cost",result)
                else:
                    result = result+ sum2
                    print(result)
ch ()
```

Comment: почему  `mon` равно `31` ?

Comment: Боюсь, вы перепутали питон и js, в питоне используется `or` вместо `|`

Comment: Что по-вашему означает выражение mon | tue | wed | thu | fri | sat | sun |0?

Comment: @ИванИпатов | тоже есть. Побитовое or. 1|2 равно 3.

Comment: @Эникейщик, вы правы, ну я не думаю, что сейчас | в коде вопроса уместен

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

# Печать стоимости проживания в зависимости от дня недели

rest_day = 2850 # баксов, к примеру
reg_day = 2100 # В обычные дни - дешевле

# Задаём связь между днём недели и стоимостью

price = {
   "mon" : rest_day,
   "tue" : reg_day,
   "wed" : reg_day,
   "thu" : reg_day,
   "fri" : reg_day,
   "sat" : reg_day,
   "sun" : rest_day,
   "quit": 77
}

# Основной цикл работы программы
while True:
    day = input("Day of week: ") # Ввод названия дня недели
    
    # Пытаемся обработать введённое значение
    try:
       pay = price[day]
       if pay == 77:
           break
       print(pay)
    except:
       print("Error day: ", day)

print("End...")
```